# Specify CSS3 Column's width

Tags: html, css

I want to make 3 columns using CSS3 column property. I also want to specify width those 3 column's width.

Is it possible to specify different width to different columns? Say I want col1 = 200px, col2 = 300px, col3=400px;

Please help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Answer (score 3):

```
#columns {
  columns:100px 3;
  -webkit-columns:100px 3; 
  -moz-columns:100px 3; 
}

<div id="columns">
   Content here here
   Content here here
   Content here here
   Content here here
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hWbxk/

Comment: That's a short hand for specifying column width, if anyone's interested in real property name, than you need to use `column-width: 100px;`, and I don't know why but this doesn't work for me -> ff22

Comment: Thanks anyway. Sorry brother i couldn't myself clear enough.
Is it possible to specify different width to different columns?
Say I want col1 = 200px, col2 = 300px, col3=400px;

Comment: @Darren Davies: Bro I want different widths of those columns.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this..

Columns : (column width) (no of column).

```
columns:10px 3;
-webkit-columns:100px 4;
-moz-columns:100px 4;
```

Comment: Ya that's what other answer says, are you repfarming? and btw, you are using 3 columns, 4 columns and 4 columns as well as width's differ

Comment: Is it possible to specify different width to different columns? Say I want col1 = 200px, col2 = 300px, col3=400px;